# Maven builds Spring Boot on local machine but not EC2 instance: UnsatisfiedDependencyException

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I've been struggling for the past few hours getting Maven to build a JAR file of my Spring Boot project in an Amazon EC2 instance. If I build with IntelliJ or with `mvn package` in my local computer, everything's fine, no problems. However, if I pull the exact same code from the same repository into the EC2 instance and build it there (both times I use Java 8, have also tried Java 11), it shows this error stacktrace:

```
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 5.373 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.courier.courier.CourierApplicationTests
[ERROR] contextLoads(com.courier.courier.CourierApplicationTests)  Time elapsed: 0.009 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
```

I'd really appreciate any help on this issue.

Here's the `pom.xml` file if that's any helpful:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.courier</groupId>
    <artifactId>courier</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>courier</name>
    <description>Courier app Spring Boot project</description>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.persistence/persistence-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    </build>

</project>
```

**EDIT:** Apparently the CourierApplicationTests class was directly at fault: removing it solved my issue. It doesn't really explain why it would build locally and not in EC2, so I'm going to keep this question open and supply the test file:

```java
package com.courier.courier;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class CourierApplicationTests {

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

Comment: Show us your configs: bootstrap.yml, application.yml or similar what you use.

Comment: @mentallurg I'm afraid I can't find any files of that sort. Anything remotely relevant is maven-wrapper.properties, which doesn't seem like a config file.

Comment: Why are you defining the version for hibernate-core on your own. I would suggest to simply add the dependency BUT without the version.

Comment: Since i see mysql dependency in your pom.xml  are you configuring your database details(url, driver class name etc) in application.properties file ?

Comment: I think I might answer my question to what really solved the problem and it was specifying the driver class name, although the one I used was deprecated, but it worked. Funny thing is, I removed it later and it continued to build normally.